# CardView default elevation value

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-elevation

I'm trying to show a badge(Pink TextView) on my CardView as below:

[image]

The elevation value of the CardView is not set, so it should be default and the elevation of the badge is set to `2dp`.

With `API Level > 22` there is no problem, but with `API Level <= 22` the badge stays under the CardView as below:

[image]

When I change the elevation value of the badge from `2dp` to `2.285738dp` then it works.

My initial idea was that the default elevation value of the CardView changes according to the API Level. Wanted to post here to find out a more logical reason for that.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_default"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_inner_half_default"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_horizontal_half_default"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?backgroundCardColor"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/accountImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_inner_default"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/accountImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accountIdText"
                style="@style/TextStyle.SemiBoldActiveMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="12058.01" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accountTypeText"
                style="@style/TextStyle.BoldSmallInactive"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                tools:text="Collection" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAmountView"
            style="@style/TextStyle.BoldPrime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivChevron"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvAmountCurrency"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivChevron"
            tools:text="13,592.04" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAmountCurrency"
            style="@style/TextStyle.BoldSmallInactive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivChevron"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivChevron"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivChevron"
            tools:text="KES" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivChevron"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_inner_default"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accountCurrencyText"
    style="@style/TextStyle.InvertedTag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_horizontal_half_default"
    android:background="@drawable/background_inverted_secondary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="KES" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing your `TextView` with the `androidx.TextView` and see if it works.

Comment: This happens in the LayoutInflater automatically, you absolutely do not have to use androidx TextViews or ImageViews in your xml files.

Comment: Replacing to androidx did not change the behavior unfortunately.

Comment: What does your `style="@style/TextStyle.InvertedTag"` and `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` do?

Comment: Is your `TextView` part of the `CardView` layout?
I assume that inside your `CardView` you have all these views with Image, Text etc.
I would set some padding/margin to the `CardView`, perhaps having the `CardView` inside a `FrameLayout` or a `ConstraintLayout` and then the Badge below the `CardView` in the hierarchy so that it would always show on top of the `CardView`.

Comment: I added the complete layout. 

`InvertedTag` is just a style in which I set `fontFamily`, `textSize`, `textColor`, etc.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting problem. This should be working 99.9% of the times. I have had some other issues with compatibility between API versions but I had always fixed it with `androidx` or `appcompat` versions of the views. Could you try the `appcompat` version of the `TextView` this time?

Comment: Changing to AppCompatTextView did not work, but changing from `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` to `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` did :)

Comment: So please accept the answer and/or update you question :) Glad my idea helped you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and fixed it by setting `elevation` for both of two items, in the background, I set `2sp` and for the item, in the foreground, I set `4sp`. and it works perfectly. 
The default value for `CardView` is `2dp`.

Comment: Seems like for Api Level <= 22; the default elevation for CardView is not `2dp` because the badge only came to foreground with elevation `2.285738dp`.